# Visual Studio 2010 URL Hyperlink color - is it possible to not use this?

Tags: url, visual-studio-2010, colors, hyperlink

Visual Studio 2010 "helpfully" detects URLs and colors them blue (by default). It will do this regardless of context - whether the URL is in the midst of XML, or it's in a comment, or it's a string in code, etc. I find this distracting. The URLs are part of their context. I'm not coding in Visual Studio in order to click on hyperlinks.

Is there any way to have Visual Studio treat URL hyperlinks the same as surrounding text? I know you can change the color from blue to something else (Tools-Options-Fonts and Colors-Display Items-URL Hyperlink). I don't want the URLs to display any specific color, but instead use the surrounding context color.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Yes: disable

Tools\Options\Text Editor\your language here\Enable single click URL navigation

to turn off the 'helpful' feature.

Comment: Yes, that worked! I was able to globally disable it in the All Languages option in Text Editor. Thanks a ton.

Comment: Nice Answer; Also to set a specific color for a .config  ( xml ) file we can use Tools =>Options => Text Editor => Environments => Fonts & Colors => for Display Name select XML Attribute Value.

Answer (score 4):

For those of you that googled into here trying to disable this on the **express** version of VS2010:

You won't find the option to remove this 'feature' under tools, and unfortunately you cannot install that VSIX from Noah Richards.

What you can do, though, is change the option directly in the registry:

**HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VCSExpress\10.0\Text Editor\CSharp**

there, change the value of "**Make URLs Hot**" to "0" and you're done.

(This is for c#. For c++ or others, I guess the path would be a bit different, but along the same lines).

Answer (score 3):

You can't do it from a setting in the product, but I just wrote an extension that does it for you (called "ClearHyperlinkForeground").  You can [download the VSIX here](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/9460c7e1-ea07-41f4-80ce-e1da4073859e).  You can also [view the source on github](http://github.com/NoahRic/ClearHyperlinkForeground), if you are curious how it works or want to build it for yourself.  It's essentially a copy of my [ItalicComments](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/0b439a8a-e21a-4e26-b82b-054fbf0acab7) extension, just modified to clear the foreground brush of the URL formatting instead of italicizing comments.

Comment: Cool! I used Brian's suggestion to turn off URL navigation, but this sounds like a great way to do customizations.